# Removing min and max number from list on the same line of code

Tags: python, python-2.7, max, min

List:

```
RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4]
```

At the moment I'm using the following method to remove both the highest and lowest number from a list:

```
RawScores.remove(max(RawScores))
RawScores.remove(min(RawScores))
```

I was wondering whether there is an alternative or more efficient method of which produces the same result but can be achieve on only one line of code.

Comment: You want to remove all joint highest values or just a single one?

Comment: Also, what's the desired behavior for a list of one element? That case behaves very differently in the answers below.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I should've stated that, Sorry. Yeah, Only the single one.

Comment: @LearningToPython Stick with what you have then, it is just fine. On a vaguely related note, for certain long lists of complex numeric types you might be interested in Raymond's code recipe here: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577916-fast-minmax-function/?in=user-178123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may seem trivial but you can put both statements on the same line:

```
RawScores.remove(max(RawScores)); RawScores.remove(min(RawScores))
```

You have the performance of modifying the list in place without having to copy it first.

In terms of performance, this is how the so far proposed methods compare (on somewhat longer lists to make the differences more apparent):

```
def a():
    RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4] * 100
    RawScores.remove(max(RawScores)), RawScores.remove(min(RawScores))

def b():
    RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4] * 100
    RawScores = [x for x in RawScores if x != max(RawScores) and x != min(RawScores)]

def c():
    RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4] * 100
    RawScores = sorted(RawScores)[1:-1]

%timeit a()  # 10000 loops, best of 3: 66.3 µs per loop
%timeit b()  # 10 loops, best of 3: 49.3 ms per loop
%timeit c()  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop
```

The original solution is the fastest so far.

And please don't take my answer too seriously. Putting multiple statements on one line like this is *horrible* practice. Python code is supposed to be beautiful not inline :)

---

Update: I ran this on another computer including two variants of the `filter` solution:

```
def d():
    RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4] * 100
    RawScores = list(filter(lambda value: (value != max(RawScores) and value != min(RawScores)), RawScores))

def e():
    RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4] * 100
    RawScores = list(filter(lambda value, ma=max(RawScores), mi=min(RawScores): (value != ma and value != mi), RawScores))


%timeit a()  # 115 µs ± 3.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit b()  # 80 ms ± 1.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit c()  # 377 µs ± 777 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit d()  # 78.7 ms ± 94.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit e()  # 458 µs ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Obviously it makes sens to compute min and max only once and not for every element. Still, in-place removal is fastest.

Comment: @timgeb When someone says "1 line" first I roll my eyes because who really needs 1 line rather than 2? And 2nd I think if you are to take on the challenge, the semi-colon is cheating, otherwise virtually all scripts can be 1 line!

Comment: So how does the solution which uses the filter in conjunction with the lambda compare?

Comment: Thanks for that, to be honest with you, the whole 1 line thing was more out of curiosity rather than practicality ;-)

Comment: @Tjaart there is not much difference between `filter` and list comprehension. @timgeb your comment made my day :) @Chris_Rands one-liners reach their limit as soon you try to start nesting blocks of code.

Comment: @Chris_Rands of course the semi-colon is cheating, that's what made the answer good and educational.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to sort and slice your list so you remove the first and last elements, unless you can't afford to have your list sorted:

```
RawScores = sorted(RawScores)[1:-1]
```

Comment: sorting adds quite some time complexity!

Comment: Yet this solution gives the same result as the original code (removing only one of multiple min/max elements).

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes it does, yet we are not being asked for speeding up the result so, this is a possibility, not a definitive one, that's for sure

Comment: They want a "more efficient method", also this doesn't modify the existing list, it creates a new one

Answer (score 2):

In one line? Yes. Efficient? No.

```
>>> RawScores = [3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4]
>>> [x for x in RawScores if x != max(RawScores) and x != min(RawScores)]
[3.4, 5.8, 7.2, 2.8, 7.6, 4]
```

This works alright, but `max` with it's O(n) complexity is called `len(RawScores)` times (same goes for `min`) which makes this solution non-efficient.

Your current solution is completely fine and runs in O(n).

Comment: This isn't what they want, it creates a new list and removes all joint highest/lowest values

Answer (score 2):

You could try with a filter:

```
nominmax = filter(lambda value: (value != max(RawScores) and value != 
min(RawScores)), RawScores)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

`without_min_max = [item for item in RawScores if item != max(RawScores) and item != min(RawScores)]`

Comment: This creates a new list, not modifying the exiting one (and removes all joint highest values; which may or may not be wanted)

Comment: And where does the question specify that this is required?

Comment: To modify the original list, simply change the left side to `RawScores[:] =`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
print(*sorted([3.4,1.2,5.8,7.2,2.8,9.1,7.6,4])[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
2.8 3.4 4 5.8 7.2 7.6
```